# Removing these first strings that are Numbers from Columns?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, multiple-columns

what is the formula for removing these first strings that are numbers from all columns?

[image: IMG]

Comment: `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))`

Comment: I made some changes to my language, but it worked very well! Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: This is possible?

Comment: Comment or answer? If it is my comment does not have, or I was blind xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some string functions to pull this off:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND(" ", A1))
```